# How to supply custom ciphers to curl to emulate browsers

Tags: ssl, curl, web-scraping, openssl, php-curl

How do I supply custom ciphers to curl for an SSL negotiation? I have have a site that is granting/denying me access based on the ciphers supplied in the “Client Hello” during the SSL Handshake. Apparently, Chrome supplies a [GREASE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8701) cipher (0x1A1A) in addition to 15 other ciphers. See https://cc.dcsec.uni-hannover.de/. It shows all the ciphers sent in the client hello along with their hexadecimal codes.

Currently, I’m supplying the 15 other ciphers using CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, but how do I supply the additional GREASE cipher? It doesn’t have a named cipher string, so I can’t supply it the usual way.

In the client hello, these cipher names are all ultimately converted to hexadecimal codes. How would I a supply custom cipher using this hex code? Can I just add 0x1a1a to CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST?

Also, I’ve verified that I’m not being denied based on another part of the request (URL, headers, IP, cookies, SSL/TLS version, HTTP version, HTTP method, etc...) so it’s definitely the cipher list. Curl is so popular and has never failed me when emulating browsers, and surely there must be a way. Oh and my curl is using [OpenSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL), not [GnuTLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GnuTLS) if that matters.

Comment: OpenSSL doesn't support GREASE ciphersuites (or extensions either). The RFCs require a server to ignore suites (and extensions, curves and sigalgs etc) it doesn't understand; the whole purpose of GREASE is to verify/enforce that, so if the server is behaving differently and wrongly based on GREASE you should report it as defective.

Comment: This is a MAJOR website, can’t tell them how to run their servers even if it doesn’t follow the RFC. 

Thinking the only way is to add my custom cipher names to the source code and compile openssl myself. There seems to be about 3-4 files that handle mapping the cipher names to the hex codes sent in the Client Hello. Will report back if this works.

Comment: The link is broken (times out): *"The connection has timed out. An error occurred during a connection to cc.dcsec.uni-hannover.de."*

Answer (score 0):

You can not simply add the *GREASE* cipher suite. As mentioned by previous comments, it's not supported by OpenSSL, which is the default SSL engine for curl on most systems.

To support the *GREASE* cipher suite, you have to compile with [BoringSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL#BoringSSL) or other SSL libraries.

But I don't think it's the CIPHER_LIST alone that was considered to block your request. TLS fingerprinting has becoming more and more popular nowadays. One of the most used one is called JA3, which considers ciphers, extensions and many other factors in the TLS Hello package.

Another technique is [HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) fingerprints, which is similar to TLS fingerprints, but it considers the settings frame and other parameters in a HTTP/2 connection.

To counter these issues, you have to build curl from the ground up with custom patches. Or use the prebuilt binaries from the *curl-impersonate* project.